# How to extracting attributes recursively in SOAP API response using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Python. I need to extract a single attribute from a xml file which is received from a SOAP API request. I need to extract the attribute 'mainAgentId' from '/type=NE/ISUKABAITHANDA_279251' and 'Bandwidth' from /type=ONT/R1.S1.LT1.PON1.ONT1. Please help with the most optimal way of checking the same. The main catch here is that there are multiple queryObject for '/type=NE' and '/type=ONT'

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <queryResponse xmlns="alu.v1">
         <queryObjectData>
            <queryObject>
               <name>
                  <tmf854:mdNm>AMS</tmf854:mdNm>
                  <tmf854:meNm>ISUKABAITHANDA_279251</tmf854:meNm>
                  <tmf854:ptpNm>/type=NE/ISUKABAITHANDA_279251</tmf854:ptpNm>
               </name>
               <vendorExtensions>
                  <package>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>hubSubtendedStatus</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value>NONE</tmf854:value>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>productAndRelease</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value>DF.6.1</tmf854:value>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>adminUserName</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value/>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>nodeModel</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value>iSAM.6.1</tmf854:value>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>envAlarmTemplate_id</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value>none</tmf854:value>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>mainAgentId</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value>113</tmf854:value>
                    </vendorExtensions>
            </queryObject>
            <queryObject>
               <name>
                  <tmf854:mdNm>AMS</tmf854:mdNm>
                  <tmf854:meNm>ISUKABAITHANDA_279251</tmf854:meNm>
                  <tmf854:ptpNm>/type=ONT/R1.S1.LT1.PON1.ONT1</tmf854:ptpNm>
               </name>
               <vendorExtensions>
                  <package>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>Bandwidth</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value>1.25 Gb/s</tmf854:value>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>bponOntAutoSwPlannedVersion</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value/>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
                     <NameAndStringValue>
                        <tmf854:name>bponOntCfgFile1Passive</tmf854:name>
                        <tmf854:value/>
                     </NameAndStringValue>
            </queryObject>
        </queryObjectData>
    </queryResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I am struggling with the below code where root has the response string.

```
    inventoryObjectData = root.find(".//{alu.v1}queryObjectData")
    if (inventoryObjectData != None):
            for inventoryObject in inventoryObjectData:
                for device in inventoryObject:
                    print("DEVICE VAL = ",device)
                    if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}mdNm") is not None:
                        mdnm = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}mdNm").text
                    if device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}meNm") is not None:
                        menm = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}meNm").text
                    if  device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}ptpNm") is not None:
                        ptpnm = device.find(".//{tmf854.v1}ptpNm").text
                        meVal = "/type=NE/"
                        ptpVal = "/type=ONT/"
                    query_vendor_ext = device.find(".//{alu.v1}vendorExtensions")
                    print("connectivityState RESPONSE ====",query_vendor_ext.find(".//{tmf854}connectivityState").text)
```

Comment: Please help us to help you by showing the code you're struggling with

Answer (score 0):

You can use an XML parsing library like `xml.etree.ElementTree` to extract the required attributes from the SOAP API response.

Here is the code that should extract the attribute 'mainAgentId' from '/type=NE/ISUKABAITHANDA_279251' and 'Bandwidth' from '/type=ONT/R1.S1.LT1.PON1.ONT1':

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# assume 'soap_response' contains the SOAP API response in string format
root = ET.fromstring(soap_response)

# iterate through all queryObject elements
for query_obj in root.findall(".//{alu.v1}queryObject"):
    query_name = query_obj.find("{tmf854}ptpNm")
    query_vendor_ext = query_obj.find("{alu.v1}vendorExtensions")
    # if queryObject contains mainAgentId attribute
    if '/type=NE/ISUKABAITHANDA_279251' in query_name.text and query_vendor_ext.find(".//{tmf854}mainAgentId") is not None:
        main_agent_id = query_vendor_ext.find(".//{tmf854}mainAgentId").text
        print(f"mainAgentId: {main_agent_id}")
    # if queryObject contains Bandwidth attribute
    elif '/type=ONT/R1.S1.LT1.PON1.ONT1' in query_name.text and query_vendor_ext.find(".//{tmf854}Bandwidth") is not None:
        bandwidth = query_vendor_ext.find(".//{tmf854}Bandwidth").text
        print(f"Bandwidth: {bandwidth}")
```

Note: The above code assumes that the SOAP API response is in a string `soap_response`. Also, the code only checks for the provided `mainAgentId` and `Bandwidth` attributes under the provided `ptpNm`. If you need to check for other attributes, you can modify the code accordingly.

Comment: The queryObjectData is not handled. How to add that ? . Also, the code does not work if there are more sections for '/type=NE' and '/type=ONT' in the response